# FTP Error;550 Filename invalid

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ftp

I have been trying simple FTP command in BASH script to put files to FTP server.

```
USERNAME="User_name_here";
PASSWORD="pass_word_here";
SERVER="ftp_url";


cd /tmp

zip -r dash.zip dash
FILE="/tmp"
echo "file zipped";

BACKUPDIR="copy_dir"

# login to remote server
ftp -n -v $SERVER <<EOF
ascii
user $USERNAME $PASSWORD
cd $BACKUPDIR
mput $FILE/dash.zip
quit
EOF
echo "done";
```

After executing I am receiving error 
550 FileName invalid
Please suggest..

Comment: Looks like you either don't have /tmp/dash.zip on your local computer or either /tmp or ./copy_dir on the remote host, do you? By the way, switching to ascii mode to upload a binary file is a bad idea.

Comment: I verified both location proper DIR has created.

Comment: Yes both directory is created by my account

Comment: Do you have permissions to write into /tmp on the remote host? (That's where the is being uploaded). As a matter of fact, you probably want to do `put $FILE/dash.zip dash.zip` to avoid absolute path issues.

Comment: If I direclty loging to FTP server and then pull the files, Files are getting copied to the remote server, but when I am trying to push it through local to remote it is giving error